# How to check if both http calls fail?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-promise

I want to make 2 http post calls, and show an error if both calls fail, if one of the calls return data, then I don't want to show the error.

```
this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson) //returns an Observable
this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson) //returns an Observable
```

Can I do this with by turning the http post into promises? I tried the code below, but it did not work. It skips the second then() and goes into catch() if the first then() throws an error, but I want it to do the next then() if the first then() throws an error.

```
this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson).toPromise()
  .then( data => {
    // do something with data
  })
  .then( _ =>
    this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson).toPromise()
      .subscribe( data => {
          // do something with data
        })
  )
  .catch( error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: The two calls depend on each other. I mean you want to make the first call and when completes you want to make the second call?

Comment: @martin, the two calls are independent, but if either one returns a result, then it will not show an error. But if both returns a HttpErrorResponse, then it will show error.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it only using `Observable` without changing it to `Promise`:

```
forkJoin(
this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson),
this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson)).subscribe (
    x => console.log(x),
    error => console.log(error)
    () => console.log('completed'))
```

The above approach may be easier than using `Promise`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not work for me. Where do you import forkJoin from?

Comment: Import forkJoin with your imports at the top like this: import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

Answer (score 0):

you could use Promise.all()

```
Promise.all(
    this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson).toPromise(),
    this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson).toPromise()
).then(response => {
    let [ response1, response2 ] = response
}).catch(err => {
    console.log({err})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With RxJS 6 you can do this with combination of `forkJoin`, `catchError` and `map` operators:

```
import { forkJoin, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const a$ = of(1);
// const a$ = throwError(new Error('Error in $a'));
// const b$ = of('a');
const b$ = throwError(new Error('Error in $b'));

forkJoin(
    a$.pipe(catchError(() => of(null))),
    b$.pipe(catchError(() => of(null))),
  ).pipe(
    map(results => {
      if (results.some(Boolean)) {
        return results;
      }
      throw new Error(`It's broken.`)
    })
  )
  .subscribe(console.log, console.warn);
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-hgcsnr?file=index.ts

Only if both sources are `false` (catch error replaced with `false`) you'll receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

```
this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson).subscribe(
  data => {
     this.http.post<any[]>(URL2, jsonBody2, postJson).subscribe(
        data2 => {
           // both calls succeeded
        }
        error => {
           // set error variable to true
        }
     )
  }
  error => {
    // set error variable to true
  }
)
```